# How get user interface like ubuntu on beaglebone black

Tags: user-interface, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am successfully bring up beaglebone black.

My question is how to get user interface like ubuntu or any other os?

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt install xfce4
```

That should do it.

I know what you mean now. Here: https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black.

That site will give you exactly what you are looking to grasp.

Comment: Thanks for replay,   I am sorry my question was not proper .My question is i downloaded kernal, uboot  and cross compiled for ARM arhitecture(beaglebone black) ,created my own rootfs.I successfully bringup my beaglebone black with my own rootfs .Here my question is i am able to use my board only command line interface.For getting UI like ubuntu  OS what should I do  ?Please help me.

Comment: Hello...yes. You only have the command line unless you use "sudo apt install xfce4" or another form. You can find many GUI to use. xfce4 is just one.

Comment: Prashanth, you can also use gnome if must be...there are many GUI from Linux distros once you get the OS on the board or the "server" as Ubuntu puts it.

Comment: Hi De Funct,my rootfs is minimal because of size construction,it don't have apt folder without installing package how to get GUI on my board